# Mvc 5 Multiselectlist selected not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc

select element created with items in it, but "selected" properties not showing in html result. What i do wrong?

**this code is working:**

controller:

```
ViewBag.ProductTwistDirectionID = new SelectList(db.tblProductTwistDirection, 
       "ProductTwistDirectionID", 
       "ProductTwistDirectionName", 
        tblProduct.ProductTwistDirectionID);
```

view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ProductTwistDirectionID", 
                   null, 
                   htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**this code is not working: (selected items not selecting at render)**

controller:

```
ViewBag.ProductUsePurposes = new MultiSelectList(db.tblProductUsePurpose,
                                                 "ProductUsePurposeID",
                                                 "ProductUsePurposeName",
                                                 tblProduct.ProductUsePurposes
                                                 .Select(x 
                                                         => x.ProductUsePurposeID)
                                                 .ToArray());
```

view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductUsePurposes, 
                      null, 
                      new 
                         { 
                           @class = "chosen-select", 
                           multiple = "multiple", 
                           data_placeholder = "Choose use purposes", 
                           style = "width: 400px;" 
                          })
```

Comment: What does `tblProduct.ProductUsePurposes.Select(x => x.ProductUsePurposeID).ToArray()` yield?

Comment: int array of 2 ids, with correct values.

Comment: Did you ever get this issue resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ViewBag` member holding the select list cannot be named the same as your model property. `ViewBag` is used, in addition to `ViewData` and `Request`, to compose the `ModelState` object and whatever is in `ModelState` overrides the properties on your model.

Simply, you need to rename `ViewBag.ProductUsePurposes` to something like `ViewBag.ProductUsePurposesChoices`. Then, you should be fine.